# Python string formatting error

Tags: python, string, formatting

I'm trying to bind a parameter in SQL:

```
sql = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE FROM USER_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME=UPPER(:TABLENAME)"
print 'TABLENAME=',TABLENAME
sqlqry = sql %(TABLENAME)
```

but get the string formatting error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: What did you expect? I don't see any valid format specifiers in your string.

Comment: If you're using `sqlite3` I'd recommend using prepared statements.

Comment: I thought the % will substitute the TABLENAME value

Comment: If you want to use a keyword in your substitution, replace `:TABLENAME` with `%(TABLENAME)s`, and then substitute like `sql % {'TABLENAME': TABLENAME}`. If you don't care about keywords, just use `%s` as mentioned below (however this introduces SQL-injection risks and prepared statements as mentioned by @Whymarrh would be the safest).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a placeholder in your string.

You want to replace `:TABLENAME` in the string `sql` with `%s` I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

You really should post a bit more code for this to be entirely clear, but it looks like the string 'sql' doesn't contain any %-codes to be substituded. You are trying to substitude one value, but not all of those were used (in other words, nothing was substituted). You should use %s instead of :TABLENAME.